# Thread local storage with __declspec(thread) fails in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++, multithreading, interop

I'm working on a project where we mix .NET code and native C++ code via a C++/CLI layer. In this solution I want to use Thread Local Storage via the __declspec(thread) declaration:

```
__declspec(thread) int lastId = 0;
```

However, at the first access of the variable, I get a NullReferenceException.
To be more precise, the declaration is done within a *ref class* (a .NET class implemented in C++/CLI).

I have already read something about __declspec(thread) does not work with delay loaded DLLs.
Am I using delay loaded DLLs automatically if I use .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that __declspec(thread) [isn't supported by CLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeremykuhne/archive/2006/04/19/578670.aspx).

Take in mind that .net threads aren't necesarily native threads, [but can be also fibers](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/15/51351.aspx), so standard API's for threads don't work on them.

If you have a managed class, then you should use managed threading API's for [thread local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.getnameddataslot(vs.80).aspx).

There are a lot of articles regarding this difference. This is just to get you started.

As a tip: You could use the ThreadStatic Attribute instead of the TLS in order to improve [performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2006/07/18/performance-quiz-10-thread-local-storage-solution.aspx). In case you are working with ASP.NET applications, you need to remember [some things](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html) about TLS.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not supported.  Here's a blog entry with a workaround:

http://blogs.msdn.com/jeremykuhne/archive/2006/04/19/578670.aspx